# The area of a right Triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

We have a right triangle here
[image: Right angled triangle]

So if i wanted to calculate the area of triangle ABC by the formula

```
   Area = 1/2*base*height
```

Can the "Hypotenuse" be considered as "base" such that the expression 1/2 *AC *BD give us the area of this Triangle ?

Comment: Yes $~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: ...........................yes

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2451599/444780

Comment: View Narashimham's answer.

Comment: I thought that the hypotenuse and base were always "separate"

Comment: The formula "area equals one half base times height" makes absolutely no reference to right triangles whatsoever and in particular works even for triangles which are not right triangles.  The formula works for any side as the base so long as you take the appropriate corresponding height to match.  The word hypotenuse is used specifically for the longest side of a right triangle, but this doesn't stop it from being *a* side of a right triangle.  The hypotenuse can also be considered as a base if you so choose.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hHzDxB7.png

Comment: @JMoravitz OK thank you.

Comment: Now, rotate that picture so that they hypotenuse is parallel to the ground.  Now the hypotenuse is the hypotenuse *and* the base and there is no perpendicular.  The base is specifically whichever side is parallel to the ground (or whichever direction you choose as your reference point) and the perpendicular (if one exists) is the one that is perpendicular to the base.

Comment: @JMoravitz are you implying that the hypotenuse becomes the base. If so could you Define "base" in a triangle because i am confused.

Comment: The base is whichever side is parallel to whichever axis we are using as a point of reference.  Usually we use the $x$-axis as our point of reference, but we are not limited to only picking that.

Comment: @JMoravitz ok thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when computing the area of a triangle, you can use any of the three sides as "$b$" in the equation $A_\triangle=\frac{1}{2}b*h$.